# Android ViewBinding Error: Cannot access class 'android.widget.no_name_in_PSI_3d19d79d_1ba9_4cd0_b7f5_b46aa3cd5d40'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewbinding

I tried to use ViewBinding in my Android Projects, because Kotlin synthetics are deprecated. I followed the official documentation from Android Developer's site. In my build.gradle.kts I enabled ViewBinding:

```kotlin
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
            viewBinding = true
        }
}
```

And I tried to use it in a Fragment like:

```kotlin
    private var _binding: FragmentStartBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = FragmentStartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }
```

But `binding.root` shows the error: `Cannot access class 'android.widget.no_name_in_PSI_3d19d79d_1ba9_4cd0_b7f5_b46aa3cd5d40'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies`.

Android Studio Version: 4.1.2
Kotlin Version: 1.4.30
Android Gradle Plugin Version: 4.1.2
Gradle Version: 6.8.1

I already tried Clean & Rebuild, Invalidate Caches & Restart, deleting .idea and .gradle folders. Also the ViewBinding files are generated, but it's impossible to use ViewBinding.

Does anybody have a solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance for any reply.

Comment: Can you please show what your xml file looks like? That would help others better understand the before and after.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error disappeared after deleting the Copyright-Comment from the layout xml file. Then it was possible for me to use Viewbinding. I hope, it will be fixed soon, so that any kind of comments in the layout files are no problem with Viewbinding.

So the top of my xml file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

**Update:**
I changed the copyright, so that the "&" is replaced with "and". That also works for me.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error because I was trying to use `dataBinding` with only `viewBinding` enabled, so enabling `dataBinding` on `app/build.gradle` solved the issue for me.

To enable:

```
android {
 ...
 buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
 ...
}
```

Comment: @RyanPayne I didn't say that, I just let the viewBinding as true because it was true in my case and I had problems with this issue because I thought they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewBinding {
    enabled = true
}

dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
```